# Can I use a Bluetooth Lavalier Mic while recording video?

Tags: bluetooth, video, microphone

I want to use a wireless Bluetooth Lavalier mic ([Like this](http://amzn.to/1J13MTu)) while recording a video. I'm open to any configuration or app to get this done.  I have a Galaxy Note 5, is there a way to get a Bluetooth (or any kind of wireless) mic that will record with the video so there is no sync issues?